# fizzBuzz array issues

Tags: javascript, arrays, fizzbuzz

I am doing a fizzbuzz challenge in JavaScript where I create a function that accepts a number and returns an array that is the length of the number. When there is a multiple of 3 it will say "fizz" and when there is a multiple of 5 it will say "buzz", and then lastly if it is a multiple of 3 and 5 it will say "fizzBuzz".

`[0, 1, 'fizz', 3, 'buzz', 'fizz', 6, 7, 'fizz', 'buzz', 10, 'fizz', 12, 13, 'fizzBuzz']`
I do it this way because the array starts at 0. But when I try to do this it ends up getting an output like this:
`['fizzBuzz', 1, 'fizz', 3, 'buzz', 'fizz', 6, 7, 'fizz', 'buzz', 10, 'fizz', 12, 13, 'fizzBuzz']`
Code:

```
    let someArray = []
   
    const fizzBuzz = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
             if (i % 3 === 0) {
                someArray.pop()
                someArray.push("fizz")
            } if (i % 5 === 0) {
                someArray.pop()
                someArray.push("buzz")
            }  if (i % 15 === 0) {
                someArray.pop()
                someArray.push("fizzBuzz")
            }   else {
                someArray.push(i)
            }
        }
    }
    fizzBuzz()
```

I have also seen where you can do it this way:

```
let someArray = []

    const fizzBuzz = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            if (i % 15 === 0) {
                someArray.push("fizzbuzz")
            } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
                someArray.push("fizz")
            } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
                someArray.push("buzz")
            }  else {
                someArray.push(i)
            }
        }
    }
    fizzBuzz()
```

This gets it right on 3 and 5, but still adds the "fizzBuzz" to the beginning of the array:
`['fizzbuzz', 1, 2, 'fizz', 4, 'buzz', 'fizz', 7, 8, 'fizz', 'buzz', 11, 'fizz', 13, 14, 'fizzbuzz']`

Is there something that I am doing wrong? and which way would be the correct way to do this? Or if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Start the loop from 1

Comment: This is correct result of fizzbuzz. Remainder of division when dividing 0 is always 0

Answer (score 1):

You can either start the loop at 1 or handle the condition for zero in the if statements...

```
const fizzBuzz = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {
              someArray.push(i)
            } else if (i % 15 === 0) {
                someArray.push("fizzbuzz")
            } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
                someArray.push("fizz")
            } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
                someArray.push("buzz")
            }  else {
                someArray.push(i)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I got tunnel vision so bad that I forgot about my loop starting at 0

Comment: Happens to everyone, that's why we have code reviews